# NAT works for Windows guests but not for Linux guests

Tags: windows-7, linux, nat, vmware-player

I have just updated to VMPlayer 4.0.3 (from 4.0.1) on a Windows 7 host.

All the various guests are configured for NAT networking and DHCP, and before the upgrade every OS could reach out the internet.

Now, out all the several guest images I have, the Linux based ones (Debian and Ubuntu, the latter with vmtools installed) cannot reach the internet anymore. With Windows based guests (all XP), everything is fine as before.

The Linux guests correctly get the IP address from the virtual DHCP. If I use Bridged mode, they can reach the internet too, but I need to avoid that.

What is the best way to troubleshoot this problem?
I have `vmnetcfg.exe` available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this was quick.

In order to make the old VMPlayer to work, I had followed the steps described [here](http://florianlr.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/5/), to enable ICS. At the end that turned out to be totally unnecessary (and as a matter of fact such solution is incompatible to Cisco VPNs), but fact is, I modified the NAT subnet to be 192.168.137.x, and it has stayed like that until today.

I re-changed the NAT subnet to the original value (192.168.175.x) and everything works: the Linux guests can reach the internet again via NAT.